# Solving a complicated system of ODEs in R, unsure if code/ method is correct

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, initial-value-problems

Apologies upfront for such a large question. Attached is a write up of the problem in case any further info is needed.

These are the equations I am trying to solve:
$$\frac{d}{dx}U_n(x)=1-U_n(x)\frac{(r-D+a)}{a}-U^2_n(x)\frac{1}{a\Delta\tau}, \>\>\>\>\> U_n(0)=0,$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}u_n(x)=-U_n(x)\frac{1}{a\Delta\tau}u_n(x)+U_n(x)\frac{v_{n-1}(x)}{a\Delta\tau}, \>\>\>\>\> u_n(0)=1,$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}z_n(x)=\Bigg(\frac{U_n(x)}{a\Delta\tau}+\frac{(r-D+a)}{a}\Bigg)z_n(x)+\frac{(u_n(x)-v_{n-1}(x))}{a\Delta\tau}, \\ z_n(L+M)=-\frac{u_n(L+M)}{U_n(L+M)}.$$
With the end goal of finding $v_n(x)=U_n(x)z_n(x)+u_n(x)$. Initial condition for $v_n(x)$ is $v_0(x)=\text{max}\{1-e^{x-L},0\}$, $1<<L\in\mathbb{R}$. (Note $L,M$ are constants where we assume $v_n(0)=1$ and $v_n(L+M)=0$). The subscript $n$ refers to the $n$ time steps we choose for the interval $(0,t_*)$, each step has size $\Delta\tau$. Essentially we use Euler's method to discretise $t$ turning our original PDE into this system of ODEs and then solve this system at each time step, giving us an approximation of $v(x,t)$. I've heard this being reffered to as using a grid or lattice to solve a PDE.

(This system is actually taken from the paper written by Jiang, Chen, Wang and Zhang: *A new well-posed algorithm to recover implied local volatility*. Appendix A.1. though I've simplified them to make $a(y)=a\in\mathbb{R}$.)

I have written some code for how I would go about solving them but the results are quite wild which makes me think I've made a mistake. I think I am right in how I have solved the first two equations, but the final one needs to be integrated backwards and this got me stuck and I think it could be what's throwing me off. This is the reverse equation I have used, is it correct? Let $1<<L,M\in\mathbb{R}$ and $w_n(s)=z_n(L+M-s)$ then
$$\frac{d}{dx}w_n(s)=-\Bigg(\frac{U_n(L+M-s)}{a\Delta\tau}+\frac{(r-D+a)}{a}\Bigg)w_n(s)+\frac{(u_n(L+M-s)-v_{n-1}(L+M-s))}{a\Delta\tau}, \\ w_n(0)=-\frac{u_n(L+M)}{U_n(L+M)}.$$

Finally, the code I've written in R.

```
tstar=1
n<-100 #determines time intervals
dt<-tstar/n
t=seq(from=0,to=tstar,by=dt)
L=100
M=100
#L,M,n and truncno (below) can all be varied to see how the plot below changes.
x=seq(from=1,to=L+M,by=0.1)
v0<-ifelse(1-exp(x-L)<0,0,1-exp(x-L)) #initial condition
#chosen constants for the problem
a=0.25
r=0.12
D=0
#blank matrix to store each successive output 
resultsmatrix=matrix(data=0,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(t))
#first column is initial condition
resultsmatrix[,1]=v0

#loop for solving the system of ODEs at each time step, note t[-1] is used here since column one of resultsmatrix is already filled with the initial condition.
for(val in (1:length(t[-1]))){
  p<-c(r,D)
  riccati<-function(times,y,parms){
    dU.dx<-1-y[1]*((p[1]-p[2]+a)/a)-(y[1]^2)/(a*dt)
    return(list(dU.dx))
  }
  y0<-0
  sol<-ode(y=y0,times=x,func=riccati,parms=p)
  linear<-function(times,y,parms){
    du.dx<-(-sol[[times,2]]*y[1]/(a*dt))+sol[[times,2]]*resultsmatrix[times,val]/(a*dt)
    return(list(du.dx))
  }
  y1<-1
  sol2<-ode(y=y1,times=x,func=linear,parms=NULL)
  linearzreverse<-function(times,y,parms){
    tt=tail(x,n=1)+1
    dw.dx<-(-(sol[[tt-times,2]]/(a*dt)+(p[1]-p[2]+a)/a))*y[1]+(sol2[[tt-times,2]]-resultsmatrix[tt-times,val])/(a*dt)
    return(list(dw.dx))
  }
  y2<-(-tail(sol2[,2],n=1)/tail(sol[,2],n=1))
  sol3<-ode(y=y2,times=x,func=linearzreverse,parms=p)
  resultsmatrix[,val+1]=sol[,2]*sol3[,2]+sol2[,2]
}
#Where you see tt-times, this is my attempt at dealing with the reversal of the equation.
#Columns of resultsmatrix are the solutions at each time step. Doing the following problem specific scalings gives us the following code
S=50
yvals=x-L
K=S*exp(yvals)
truncno=100
persp(x=head(K,n=truncno),y=t,z=head(S*resultsmatrix,n=truncno),
      xlab="K",ylab="t",zlab="V(K,t)", theta = 50, phi = 25,
      ticktype="detailed",axes=T)
#This plot is what looks to wild to me.
```

[Additional Write Up Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWV7o.png)

[Additional Write Up Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFhRV.png)

[Additional Write Up Part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KGaM.png)

Comment: Try refactoring your code into a lot of short, simple functions you can test individually. This isn't just a good coding practice; it'll also make people more likely to help. If in doing so you find a problem in a small region, but still don't understand its cause, you can ask a question about that. However, you may find this isn't the best stack exchange for the question, once you've narrowed down the scope of it.

Comment: How would I do that when it comes to elements in a recursive loop? I'm all self taught so my coding background is shoddy at best. But thanks for your advice! Do you know which stack exchange would be better?

Comment: It looks like you can take some definitions outside the for loop. The right SE depends on what turns out to be at fault. If the issue is a particular bit of code not doing what you'd expect, stack overflow might be helpful. But be warned: you need to ask them about a very small piece of code if you want them to be kind.